# python apscheduler does nothing

Tags: python

I made the following ,but it doesn't print the time.

```
   from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
    from datetime import datetime 
    
    def tick():
        print('Tick! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())
    
    
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(tick,'interval',seconds=3)
    print('starting')
    scheduler.start()
    print('stopped')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your program is exiting before the interval has elapsed and needs to be kept alive at least until the first interval, consider using the following example:

```
while True:
  #Thread activity here (time.sleep(2) for example)
```

or using other forms of activity to keep your main thread alive. Or just print out the time without this scheduling if that's what you really need.